# How to add a new language Support in Lucene Solr

Tags: search, indexing, solr, lucene, nlp

It seems to me that lucene currently does not support bengali; how can i add support for bengali content?
and what nlp methods(stemming, tokenizing etc.) lucene uses for indexing and search?

my content will be mainly in bengali and with some english words

thanks

edit: it seems there are some info here, but it does not contain enough detail.

```
http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/IndexingOtherLanguages
```

Comment: [`StandardAnalyzer`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html) is intended to be language-agnostic, so it might serve your purposes.  If you want to include language-speciffic analysis, such as stemming, there are a number of [language analyzers available](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/) that you could use as an example to work from.  The Indic filters (lucene/analysis/in) and Hindi analyzer (lucene/analysis/hi) might provide some useful tools, as well.

Comment: thank you for your reply. i will look there. However i suppose that it([tag:standardanalyzer]) will just tokenize using whitespace as the stopwords are specific to English, any detailed indexing will need language specific directions.

Comment: No, it doesn't just tokenize at whitespace.   See [UAX #29](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Word_Boundaries).  And stop words are configurable.